# Why linearlayout's size -1?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get linearlayout's size.

I tested as following code.

But I just get value -1 (linearlayout's width).

How to get correct size?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
package com.example.LayoutSize;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();

        System.out.printf("linearLayout width : %d", layoutParams.width);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `-1` is because the `width` parameter is set to `MatchParent` which has a value `-1`.

To get the size of a layout, your should be using `getWidth()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` methods.  However, these methods won't give you a meaningful answer until the view has been measured. Read about [how android draws views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) here.

You can get the correct size, by overriding the `onWindowFocusChanged()` as [mentioned in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/nNEp6xBnPiw).

Alternatively, (*hacky solution*), you could do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    linearLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("linearLayout width : %d", linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: And the 'hacky solution' is hacky because...?

Comment: It works mostly, but I am not sure if the framework provides any guarentee that `post` will always be done after the layout has been measured.. maybe in future version.. they tweak the measuring and layout mechanism and we may find that `post` happens before.. i don't think this is officially documented..

Comment: That may very well be because you're supposed to post the view's *parent*, in stead of the view itself, since the parent lays out its children. That is, a child view may not accurately know whether it has actually finished laying out, but the parent should. There's an example of this approach in the ["Managing Touch Events in a ViewGroup" article](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate).

Comment: Yes.. that is a good observation. Thanks for pointing it out.. will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
```